# How to return a partial view in a controller in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, partial-views

I have a controller and one of its methods (actions) access my database of items. That method checks the item type. How do I show my partial view only if the item retrieved from my database is of a specific type?

Controller Action example:

```
public ActionResult CheckItem(Koko model)
{
    var item = db.Items.Where(item => item.Number == model.Number).First();
    if(item.Type=="EXPENSIVE")
    {
       //show partial view (enable my partial view in one of my Views)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could return a PartialView action result:

```
public ActionResult CheckItem(Koko model)
{
    var item = db.Items.Where(item => item.Number == model.Number).First();
    if (item.Type=="EXPENSIVE")
    {
        return PartialView("name of the partial", someViewModel);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the controller action will return partial HTML. This obviously means that you might need to use AJAX in order to invoke this controller action otherwise you will get the partial view replace the current browser window. In the AJAX success callback you could reinject the partial HTML in the DOM to see the update.

Comment: ahaha... i think what i am doing is wrong... actually, my partial view only contains buttons... if the item is a specific type, it will just show additional buttons in the browser.... in  return PartialView("name of the partial", someViewModel); what is someViewModel, my partial view only contain buttons...

Comment: If you don't need to have a model you could omit this argument. It basically represents the model that you could pass to the partial view.

Comment: I think this isn't something you should do in your controller. It is only UI related, and thus should be handled in your View. Just check in your View whether your model has a certain Type (your property) and add buttons accordingly.
This answer by Darin shows exactly what you asked, but is not what you want (which is due to your poor problem description).

Comment: i know that it is more of a UI related problem... however, is it a good practice to put a query/lambda code in your View? i also want to check my item type in my View how could i do that without showing query codes in my View?

Comment: You indeed shouldn't query your database in your UI; however, what is your setup? How do you call this method? With a little bit more information we might give you more and better advice to solve this problem (rather than a quick fix).