# ASP.NET MVC - Partial view with model inside another view with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I would appreciate some advice to my following problem.

I have a page with a form which always should prompt the user like this:

//Create.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

But then I want to show a different partial depending on which id is sent as querystring
?id=1

Eg. if id is 1, then i want to show

//_Attributes1.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Size)
```

and if id is 2

//_Attributes2.cshtml

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Brand)
```

So when id is 1, then the page should be like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Size)
```

I imagine my Models will be like:

```
public class ProductModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes { }

public class Attributes1 : Attributes {
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
public class Attributes2 : Attributes {
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Any input on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596434/125740

Comment: You just need to have different Partial views, and return respective Partial View depending on your business case.

Comment: Yahya, but it should not just return the partial view, it should also return the "surrounding" create.cshtml. Or am I misunderstanding some thing?

Comment: Simple structure would be, inside you Create.cshtml, you ask for a partial view, the action behind that partial view would go on and do the checks and return relevant Partial View (and View Model). This is all within create.cshtml, because as the name suggest "Partial View". Hope it helps